# Pygame, making pong

Tags: pygame

Can anyone help me out, I can't figure out why the code does not run. I feel like it is a really stupid mistake any maybe a better, second pair of eyes could lend me a hand?
It's saying my post is mainly code so I need to add some 'description', so you don't have to read this, I'm just doing this so it will let me post it.

```
#my pong game

import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

#global variables
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 800
game_over = False
ball_speed_x = 15
ball_speed_y = 15
ball_width = 15
ball_height = 15
ball_color = (255,0,0)
ball_posx = int(screen_width/2 - (ball_width / 2))
ball_posy = int(screen_height/2 - (ball_width / 2))





screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('PONG')

#player blueprint
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = 100
        self.width = 20
        self.vel = 15
        self.color = (255,0,0)
        self.player = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.player)

#creating objects
player1 = Player(10, int(screen_height/2 - 5))
player2 = Player(screen_width - 30, int(screen_height/2 - 5))
ball = pygame.Rect(ball_posx, ball_posy, ball_height, ball_width)

        
def player_animation():  
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player2.y -= player2.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player2.y += player2.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player1.y -= player1.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player1.y += player1.vel

def ball_animation():
    global ball_posx, ball_width, ball_height, ball_posy, ball_posx, ball_speed_x, ball_speed_y, screen_width, screen_height
    if ball.right >= screen_width - 5:
        ball_speed_x *= -1
    if ball.left <= 10:
        ball_speed_x *= -1
    if ball.bottom >= screen_height - 5:
        ball_speed_y *= -1
    if ball.top <= 5:
        ball_speed_y *= -1
    if player1.player.colliderect(ball):
        ball_speed_x *= -1
    if player2.player.colliderect(ball):
        ball_speed_x *= -1
    
    ball_posx += ball_speed_x
    ball_posy += ball_speed_y
    
    
    
    
while not game_over:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    ball_animation()
    player_animation()
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255,0,0), ball)
    player1.draw()
    player2.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Use [pdb](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) or debugger of your IDE and you can observe your code step-by-step in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your code works fine apart from the draw functions. In the player class, you create the player's rectangle at the beginning and it's x and y values aren't changed throughout the game, you're simply changing the variable that was used to create the rectangle when instead you should be changing the rectangle's actual x and y variables. This can be fixed by adding these two lines in the player class:

```
    def draw(self):
        self.player.y = self.y
        self.player.x = self.x
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.player)
```

The self.player.y will update the rectangle's y value to the player's current value so the rectangle is drawn in the right place.

The ball has the same problem, the eclipse is created once but it's x and y values are never changed.
Instead of writing:

```
ball_posx += ball_speed_x
ball_posy += ball_speed_y
```

Do :

```
ball.x += ball_speed_x
ball.y += ball_speed_y
```

which directly access the eclipses x and y values so it can be redrawn in the right place. I made the changes stated here and everything started moving fine.

Comment: That's alright, I've made the same mistake many times because it's really difficult to spot, It seems that by changing the variables used to set a shape's position you can move it but it's important to remember that changing variables used to create an object won't actually change the object's attributes.